# Is it possible to create Windows Form apps on Mac OS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer, macos-high-sierra

I'm studying Informatics Engineering, and my teacher uses a Windows PC to teach us Windows Forms. My question is: Can I do my Windows Forms homework on my mac? I'll install Visual Studio of course.

Comment: Install VirtualBox and install a Windows VM? Is that an option? If not, Amazon Workspaces work wonderfully.

Comment: For a course like that, you do need a Windows machine, virtual or physical, so as to follow the teacher's setup. Windows Forms is Windows only, and the cross platform implementation from Mono is incomplete and should be avoided. Though of course, if I am the teacher, I will choose some other UI frameworks to teach, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea so that my students can use any OS they like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you do the Windows Forms homework on your Mac?  Maybe.

- As mentioned, [Mono has an implementation of Windows Forms](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/).  There has been recent activity in this area ([early 2018](https://www.infoq.com/news/2018/02/mono-forms-carbon64)).
- [Visual Studio for Mac](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/) is not actually regular Visual Studio.  It's a re-branding of [MonoDevelop](https://www.monodevelop.com/).

Should you try to do the Windows Forms homework on your Mac?  Probably not.

- The Mono version is a different implementation of Forms and you're going to run into bugs, missing features, etc.
- You're going to end up debugging environment differences.  Mono/OSX vs Windows, VS for Mac vs VS proper, etc.
- You'll end up in more trouble if they provide bat/powershell scripts, require another Windows-only library, etc.

The end result being either you'll spend a lot of time trying to use things you receive from someone else, or (even worse) they won't be able to run what you turn in.

Alternatives:

- As has also been mentioned, you can run Windows in a VM like [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), [Parallels](https://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/), or [VMWare Fusion](https://www.vmware.com/products/fusion.html).  [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) is free.
- Use a computer lab at your school with Windows machines
- Work remotely via: [Microsoft Remote Desktop](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id1295203466?mt=12),  [Apple Remote Desktop](https://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/), [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing), etc.