# How to create a windows form application on Mac

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio

I was trying to start coding in C# using Visual Studio on my Mac, following a tutorial on how to create a Windows form application, here (Visual studio for Mac 2022 preview) I can't see any of this, so, how can I do that? Thank you for the help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52371387/is-it-possible-to-create-windows-form-apps-on-mac-os

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52371387/is-it-possible-to-create-windows-form-apps-on-mac-os

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, WinForms is not supported on MacOS. There are other GUI alternatives (Avalonia, or the new Maui) that are.

It might be possible to get a WinForms app to work with Mono, but I wouldn't try that for a new project, because Mono is deprecated and only works with .NET Framework, which in turn is not supported as a development environment on the Mac.